# Connect SPI display to raspberry pi zero

Tags: gpio, spi

I would like to use this display with my raspberry pi zero w.

http://uk.farnell.com/midas/mcot128032cy-ws/display-oled-tab-128x32-pixels/dp/2769715

I can see there is a flat ribbon for the SPI interface on the display, how do I connect it to the PI GPIO?

Comment: You should be motre specific and show what research you have done before posting!

Comment: that's all I knew. I'm a software dev, not an engineer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With difficulty.

Those FFC/FPC cables aren't used with the hobbyist in mind.

I suppose if you are an expert wirh a soldering iron you could attempt to solder jumper leads to the contacts.

Otherwise try googling for FFC/FPC to jumper leads.